# Files not copied to laptop when transferred via USB from Nexus 5

Tags: usb, 5.0-lollipop, file-transfer

I have downloaded a 3 gb folder of android tutorials from torrent on my nexus 5.Now I am trying to copy that folder through USB to my laptop but unfortunately everytime I try to copy it I get a blank folder.When I try separately to copy those media files I am unable to copy them.Please help me fix this.
 P.S. My phone is connected as a media device via usb and recently I upgraded it to lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with Motorola Moto G 1st and 2nd gen after Lollipop update. All the files will be able to be transferred after a restart but no new files after the restart is transferable. You must restart your device after every new files download to be copied to your PC via USB.

Comment: Have you looked at the  solutions [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323)? IDT you'll have to restart ever again.