# Alternatives for MTP, PTP and USB Storage regarding data transfer in Android 4.x.x and 5.0

Tags: usb-connection-mode, mtp

It has been known that **USB Storage** functionality was removed in Android 4.4.x and subsequent version of Android.

**PTP** doesn't work very well on cross-platforms, not to mention it restricts files to certain media types.

**MTP** works in Windows and in some Linux distributions with certain tweaks. However, it is not very stable and breaks often when transferring huge files (on all of my three Android devices).

The question is to suggest some good alternatives for file transfer between Desktop and Android without compromising data transfer speed (via USB cable). It implies that no data transfer apps using hotspot/wifi should be suggested like Airdroid, WeLine, Webkey *et al*.

Note that the solution should work on at least all of the Android 4.x.x versions and possibly on 5.0 too. A similar question was asked [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-wireless-file-transfer) but its limited to Android 4.0.x.

Comment: The other question isn't limited to 4.0.  I've merged to shift over your answer.