# I cannot see folders on my sd card

Tags: sd-card, lg-g3, hidden

I was trying to transfer some music into my phone so as usual I connected it with my USB, however, out of the 48 folders I have I could only see 14... I already tried to check the "hidden" folders but I'm still not able to see those folders. Help please? BTW, I have a LG G3 phone, in case anyone wants to know.

Comment: Connect as Mass Storage mode instead of MTP mode.

Comment: @MANI As per this [page](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g3-6294.php) and some others on web, this device comes preloaded with Kitkat which doesn't provide USB Mass Storage Mode. //Mary: If it helps, you may consider  this app called [MTP Alternative](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clearevo.mtp_alternative) which can enable you to see all the folders that you are able to see in Android itself. Otherwise, you may look at any method described in my answer here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323