# How can I view/transfer non-image files from my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini to my computer?

Tags: file-transfer

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini running Android 4.4.2 (KitKat), and a computer running Ubuntu 12.04.

When I plug the phone into the computer using the USB cable that came with the phone, the phone gives a notification that says "connected as an installer", and it shows up on my computer as a folder containing some unidentifiable files.  When I click the phone notification I can change it to connect as either "Media device (MTP)" or "Camera (PTP)".

When I connect with MTP, the phone shows up on my computer as a folder containing all the same folders that it actually contains (as viewed from ES File Browser on the phone), but from the computer those folders all appear empty.

When I connect with PTP, the phone again shows up on my computer as a folder containing all the correct folders, and this time most of the folders' contents are shown as well.  However, only image files seem to be shown (for example, I see .gif, .jpg, and .png files, but not .ogg or .mp4 files).

So, two questions:

1. Is it possible to make the other files show up, or not?
2. If not, is there any app that makes it possible?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323

Answer (score 0):

First, when you say unidentifiable files what are you referring to? Second, PTP is only gonna display video based files(exactly the types you listed although .ogg is usually used for ring tones and such). Keep in mind that even though Android is a GNU based operating system, it may sometimes require a few tweeks in the terminal along with ADB to get it functioning properly with your device, hence the computer folders appearing empty.

Comment: By "unidentifiable files" I'm referring to files that don't correspond to any files that I can see on the phone's file system using ES File Browser.  I'm not sure what you mean by "video based files" - for me, it showed image files but not video files (mp4).  Do you have any idea *what* tweaks might be needed to make the video files visible?

Comment: I use Linux and on my system it will prompt me to view In PTP either image or video files in VLC player. That's what I meant by tweak because VLC usually requires a little setup in the terminal to get it working properly or you could use ADB to push whatever files you need to your device or vice versa.  I'm going to cut away to try your scenario(If you are a Windows user) and will return with a comment.

Comment: Tried mounting my device since i also have a Galaxy S4 mini. PTP uses camera software and is used for images. .ogg is technically an audio file format and .mp4 is video not imaging since PTP(Picture Transfer Protocol) handles digital images only. When the device is mounted you should be able to see your files normally in MTP and only the digital image files in PTP.  Your situation appears to be reverse. As stated by itechy21 try reinstalling your USB and device drivers.

Answer (score -1):

You Could try samsung Kies. However it's a horrible piece of software (IMO).
Download Link: [Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/)

And if that doesn't work try reinstalling your device drivers (which Kies does for you)

Comment: There does not seem to be a version of Kies that works on Ubuntu.