# Color Scheme with Vim on Android?

Tags: terminal

I am trying to get a "solarized dark" colorscheme to work with Vim on android. Vim itself runs, and the plugin itself runs, but the colorscheme comes out wrong. I am using jackpal.androidterm app (usually the first one you see if you search 'terminal' on google play). I have tried exporting nearly every terminal type, both through the app and throught a script and I have the app's colorscheme set to "solarized dark", however, the backround doesn't display properly.

[Here are the Screenshots for it.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8d96ec3eec9c6f2!536&authkey=!AL9MIlBQVx8v7xY&ithint=file%2Cdocx)

Due to limitations on new users, I pasted them in OneDrive. (They were packed in a document due to an odd bug when uploading with Dolphin.)

Also, It is worth noting that solarized "works" on the Android Terminal when TERM=xterm-256color. However, the limited solarized colorset has too little contrast and is just plain ugly. In addition, both systems have the same plugins and .vimrc:

(~/.vimrc)

```
syntax on
set number
set ruler

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

 Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
 Plugin 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'

 " Unite
 " "   depend on vimproc
 " "   ------------- VERY IMPORTANT ------------
 " "   you have to go to .vim/plugin/vimproc.vim and do a ./make
 " "   -----------------------------------------
 Plugin 'Shougo/vimproc.vim'
 Plugin 'Shougo/unite.vim'

 Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
 Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
 Plugin 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 call vundle#end()            " required
 " filetype plugin indent on    " required
 " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
 filetype plugin on
 " "
 " " Brief help
 " " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
 " " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just
 " :PluginUpdate
 " " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
 " " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to
 " auto-approve removal
 " "
 " " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
 " " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

 " -- solarized personal conf
 set background=dark
 try
     colorscheme solarized
     catch
 endtry

 " Highlight 80th column
 if (exists('+colorcolumn'))
     set colorcolumn=80
         highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=9
 endif


 " bindings for unite--------------------------------------------------

 let g:unite_source_history_yank_enable = 1
 try
   let g:unite_source_rec_async_command='ag --nocolor --nogroup -g ""'
   call unite#filters#matcher_default#use(['matcher_fuzzy'])
 catch
 endtry
 " search a file in the filetree
 nnoremap <space><space> :split<cr> :<C-u>Unite -start-insert file_rec/async<cr>
 " reset not it is <C-l> normally
 :nnoremap <space>r <Plug>(unite_restart)

 " Bindings for Ag ------------------------------------------------------------
 " --- type ° to search the word in all files in the current dir
 nmap ° :Ag <c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr><cr>
 nnoremap <space>/ :Ag

 " Easy align interactive--------------------------------------------------
 vnoremap <silent> <Enter> :EasyAlign<cr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot of the desired color scheme, I can confirm that you can have such color scheme in Android. This is a rather indirect way but works fairly well.

Rather than using a terminal emulator I'm using an SSH client having color schemes. Three useful apps I found are [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh), [Serverauditor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client) and [Reflection for Unix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rTablet.Android). I tested the first two apps.

Why SSH client you may ask? Because I stumbled across one of them and this question struck me as well. Anyhow, we need to host a simple and easy SSH server on your Android device.

I prefer [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro)(paid) but you may use [SSH Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sshserver&hl=en)(free) too. Both offered by same developer, though feel free to use any server app that can setup SSH server.

#### Instructions

1. Open any of these server apps and make an SSH server with credentials. It's extremely easy so no instructions are required here. However, you may take a look at [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277)(**Method #3**) for basic *know-how*.

   A thing to note that free version will make your server available on all network interfaces (including cellular network) which one won't prefer for some reasons. That's why I use the paid version as it can limit it to `127.0.0.1` or Wi-Fi easily.
2. Install and launch JuiceSSH and enter SSH server details:

   - *Addresss*: `127.0.0.1` (Only for Pro app, for free app the IP will be listed)
   - **Identity → New** → type **Username** and **Password** you created in step 1.
   - *Port*: you entered in step 1.

   Save it.
3. Tap the new entry in connections and select **Accept** to accept server fingerprints.
4. **Solarized dark** is available under its **Settings → Theme/Colors**.

   A look of this app in the said theme:

   [image: Solarized dark on JuiceSSH]

   <sub>(*Click image to see larger variant.*)</sub>
5. If you want more options in color scheme then try Serverauditor(Solarized default) app. Its options are straightforward, but it did not work in my device on `127.0.0.1` (no error, just blank toast).

   You may try it running on said address; could be device specific problem on my side. Otherwise, either use the cellular IP or if you're connected to Wifi/hotspot then use that one.

   A look of Serverauditor in Solarized dark theme:

   [image: Serverauditor in Solarized dark theme]

   <sub>(*Click image to see larger variant.*)</sub>

---

### About JuiceSSH

> The all in one terminal client for Android including SSH, Local Shell, Mosh and Telnet support.
>
> Features:
>
> - Full colour terminal / ssh client
> - Popup keyboard with all those normally hard to find characters
> - Use the volume keys to quickly change font size
> - External keyboard support
> - Local Android terminal support
> - Dark, Light, 80's hacker, Molokai, **Solarized Dark** and Solarized Light terminal color themes
>     ...

### About Serverauditor

> Serverauditor is the most innovative SSH client ever designed for a mobile device. With Serverauditor you can easily manage UNIX/Linux servers from your Android device on the go.
>
> - XTerm, VT100 and vanilla terminal types support
> - SSH key and password authentication
> - Built-in RSA/DSA key generator
> - Multiple SSH connections to the same host
> - Bluetooth keyboard support
> - Associate volume button or shaking gesture with actions, e.g Ctrl-Z or session closing
> - **8 awesome color schemes and adjustable font size**
> - Automatic UNIX/Linux OS recognition, e.g Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, Mac OS X etc
>     ...

---

<sub>Perhaps all of this can be avoided if only we can have a Terminal app with color schemes. Do let me know, otherwise this solution should be enough. :)</sub>

Comment: That is a confirmed solution to the problem. However, this terminal emulator I am trying to use does support colorschemes and it gets pretty close. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidte) 
 - I would love to find a way to use it with that, since I really like the keybindings of that terminal emulator.

Comment: @deathbyfreezeray I just posted as an alternative since I felt there should be one. However, if you do happen to complete your solution then do post it as an answer, otherwise, you may accept/upvote this answer if you think it suffices.

Comment: I will update if I find anything but for now thanks, sadly I am too low reputation to upvote...