# How to use terminal to ssh access my server

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux, ssh

Can I ssh into a `linux Server` from my android device.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access a Linux server using SSH protocol from your Android device. You'll need an app or SSH binary to do this. My Lollipop seems to have in-built SSH so I can always use it using ADB or through [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). The default usage parameters are same as in the desktop. You can see more parameters by typing `ssh` if your device has the binary.

If you don't seem to have one, then  no worries. You can use an app like [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) or [Serverauditor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client) or [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside). I've covered first two apps in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111109/96277) and the interface makes it straightforward to use (if you're aware of SSH on Linux). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are plenty solutions, just look for SSH client on app market or on [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the simplest option is to get a 3rd party app and use that.
However if you want to do it from a terminal-type interface "natively" then it is not always quite so simple.
You will first need an app like Terminal Emulator. Some custom ROMs include the ssh binaries so you can just type `ssh youruser@yourserver` and all will be fine. If your ROM does not have ssh then it is a lot more complex, and you will need a rooted device.

You might be able to find a `dropbear-ssh` compiled binary for your device or a similar device - however the dropbear binary I found seemed to be lacking certain newer encryption protocols and I could not log into some ssh servers without changing server-side settings. SSH-keygen was also not provided as far as I could tell.

The next alternative is to find compiled binaries for your android version and then copy the binaries (`ssh` and `ssh-keygen`) into `/system/xbin` and the library file (`libssh.so`) into `/system/lib` and change the permissions.
In my case I managed to find and use a 4.3 compiled binary in a 4.4.4 device.

Comment: What makes this different from [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/111945/16575)? Apart from the "maybe" which you pointed out yourself having issues.