# Linux Elementray Os Luna not showing in my devices when I connect my Asus Zenfone 5

Tags: linux

[image]

It seems to work fine in other Windows based laptops but when I connect it to my Dell (with Elementary Luna) it doesn't show in my devices but it still charges. I have turned on MTP and also USB Debugging so what am i missing here?

Comment: Do you have MTP installed? What does `mtp-detect` shows? In my Mint (variant of Ubuntu, like Luna) I sometimes use [GMTP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gmtp/) since my device doesn't show up in default file manager. However, regularly I prefer access over FTP. I made a [guide here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323) as well (you may try it if MTP doesn't work somehow).