# Connect LG G3 Android phone to Linux PC

Tags: adb, linux, file-transfer, mtp

I just want to access the files on my Verizon LG G3 phone from my Linux PC.

I have `adb` installed and I followed this [ArchLinux tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Connecting_to_a_real_device_-_Android_Debug_Bridge_.28ADB.29) but `adb devices` outputs the following:

```
[grease-lightning]/home/lucas$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

I also followed this [xda-developers tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-connecting-lg-g3-to-linux-adb-aka-t2821673) but the MTP tool does not seem to detect my device properly.

I have usb debug on, and MTP mode on, (via `Settings > Storage > usb/pc connection > "MTP" (default was PTP)` on my Android phone).

I also tried running the commands `mtp-detect` with [this output](http://codepad.org/nrAOwaiR) and `mtp-connect` with [this output](http://codepad.org/fKRH62qx), but I cannot seem to access the file system. Most notably, it seems that the vender and product id are not detected, as quoted here from the `mtp-detect` output:

```
Device 0 (VID=1004 and PID=627f) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
   Found 1 device(s):
   1004:627f @ bus 3, dev 25
```

As instructed in the `xda` tutorial, here are the contents of my udev file:

```
[my-pc]/home/lucas$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="1004",ATTR{Product}=="627f",MODE="0666"
```

and here is the `lsusb` info for clarification:

```
[grease-lightning]/home/lucas$ lsusb | grep LG
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 1004:627f LG Electronics, Inc.
```

So, after trying these tutorials using the mtp and adb approaches, how can I connect to the files/media on my Android phone? Any suggestions?

I am using ArchLinux if that matters, and I would prefer a simple CLI approach to accessing the files on my phone.

Comment: If the goal is to only copy files to-and-fro the device then consider [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) which will need hotspot on your device or USB tethering enabled or internet access, and then using an app to host an FTP server on your device. You can then access it from PC locally. You can use `curlftpfs` on Linux to mount FTP server on your PC and then access anything from CLI.

Comment: And sometimes, it happens with people that using root account on Linux and then connecting you device with Linux results in access to ADB and MTP on the device. I use root for it and never had to use udev rules or something.