# Manage files in Android phone from PC hangs

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I always get unstable file management with my  Android phones while they are connected to Windows 8 PC. It takes too long to create directory in phones card. Window freezes when I try to rename folder. Sometimes not all files are copied to device when I for example select whole directory copy. Where is problem?

Comment: By "[phone's] card" are you referring to internal SD card? I suppose the problem is with MTP which you may be using to transfer files across the two devices. Did you try any other method to transfer files? What are your results? You can see some of the alternatives ways of file transfer here: [Is there a viable alternative to MTP for file transfer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900)

Comment: I suggest you use a different cable and sytem and post your observations here. That would narrow down your problem as to what actually is causing the problem(ie. cable, phone, PC)