# adb pushed file not showing over MTP

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one, mtp

I want to copy a file ~5G to my Oneplus One(running cm-12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K6) over MTP, but it fails at finishing copying. The copied file is 0KB so I delete it. Later I successfully copy the file over adb but I can't see the file over MTP when the phone is booted. I can only see the file over MTP when the phone is in twrp recovery.

There are some similar questions on this site but the answers don't work.

What I have tried:

1. Clear data on the Media Storage application and reboot. Doesn't help.
2. adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard. Doesn't help too. What's worse is that now I see even less files over MTP. I can only see all the files over MTP when the phone is in recovery.
3. Settings → Developer options → Development tools → Media Provider → Scan SD Card. Doesn't help.

[edit] Deleting that large file and rescaning SD card makes all the files visible again over MTP. With that file on my phone, scanning SD card never finishes. For now I can only avoid saving large video files on the phone due to this glitch.

Comment: MTP sucks (at least for me), so I once looked for alternative solutions and  came up with this post: [Is there a viable alternative to MTP for file transfer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900) They may look odd at first  but they are easy to follow in daily use.