# How to update a text file using both a desktop text editor and an android phone?

Tags: sync, text-editor

I do most of my text edits on my desktop (using a text editor), but sometimes I'd like to edit them on my phone. I know that one alternative is creating a shortcut to my desktop text file, dragging it to the Dropbox folder, opening the Dropbox app on my phone, looking for the file, and editing it with an android editor (Jota, for example). This is a bit cumbersome.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to edit files using a text editor (so, no Google Docs) and keep editing on my phone.

Comment: What are the specific requirements then? Aka why not Google Docs? I've written code in Google Docs before, then copy/paste into the valid file extension. Is the extension/encoding what you're trying to preserve?

Comment: It depends upon the lengths you would go to do something. E.g. you can run a file server on your android and mount the server as a drive/partition in your PC. Keep the files in your phone so that you can edit them even in offline mode. You can edit them in PC through the mounted drive. // Another example: run a file server on PC and keep the files there. In phone, access the server using a file explorer app and edit the files using any text editor. This requires a server to always be running on your PC. In both the cases, you can  sync the files in both the device and the PC.

Comment: @AaronGillion I want to be able to use my existing text editor (Sublime Text) and I don't think there's a way to do that through Google Docs

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the suggestions. So I guess the answer is that there is no straightforward way. What android file server would you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what's not straightforward about browsing for the file in an app and clicking it to open it with the editor you want i.e. your existing process. What step are you hoping to eliminate?

Comment: @nachocab:  See Method 1 or Method 3 in my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277). They would work for both Wi-Fi and USB tethering.

Comment: Why not simply mount your cloud storage (Dropbox, ownCloud, Drive, whatever) on both ends, and put your documents in there? Easy to do. ownCloud even comes with a web-based editor for OpenDocument format, so you could use your browser for editing as well.

Comment: Google Drive lets you [sync files to your computer](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374983). Then you can edit them however you want.

Comment: Have you tried [Standard Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.standardnotes)?

Answer (score 1):

Create an account with Evernote and download that app. on your phone. It will synch whatever you enter on any piece of kit you have it on.